# How to solve the ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is the following ordinary differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(0.1/x)}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{1-a/x^7}\right]$$

My Professor says that integration of the above ODE, gives the relationship between "$y$" and "$x$".

But I don't know how the above ODE is solved. Does someone know, how the equation is solved?

"Thank you"

Answer (score 2):

Your equation can be written as

$${{dy} \over {dx}} =  - {1 \over {10}}{1 \over {{x^2}}}\left[ {{1 \over {1 - a{x^{ - 7}}}}} \right]$$

This means $y$ is some function such that $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ equals what is on the RHS of the above. Can you find $y$? That is, your equation is

$$y'=f(x)$$

for $$f(x)=- {1 \over {10}}{1 \over {{x^2}}}\left[ {{1 \over {1 - a{x^{ - 7}}}}} \right]$$

Comment: Now you integrate both sides with respect to $x$.  Don't forget the constant (on one side)

Comment: Did you answer some now deleted comment, @Ross ?

Comment: No, I though this suggestion should be added.  People new to differential equations may not know you can do that.  It wasn't worth another answer given what you had done.

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, OK. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Peter, "Thank you" to answer my question. But my problem has been finding y. If you can please help me.

Comment: @Mehdi To be honest, the equation has a very ugly solution. You can check Wolfram Alpha to see it, though.

Comment: Thank you Peter,it was very useful to me

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Nicely directed hint.